# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un directorio desde una view en Django?

Tags: django

Quiero crear un nuevo directorio usando una función en mis views. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando la librería os.

Sería algo así:

```
import os

os.mkdir('/path/to/directory/', mode=0755)
```